# jQuery .animate function won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>
<p class="question">QUESTION1</p>
<p class="answer">ANSWER1</p>
<p class="question">QUESTION2</p>
<p class="answer">ANSWER2</p>
```

This is the JavaScript/jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).next('.answer').css('display') === 'none') {
      $(this).next('.answer').animate({ "display": "block" }, 1000 });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem in that on click the function does not work - the display of the .answer p does not change.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: You can't animate display. Use `fadeIn()` instead.

Comment: Are you sure the `if()` is matching? `.css()` won't pick up styles inherited from stylesheets, it only accesses inline style attributes.

Comment: You should use `if ($(this).next('.answer').is(':hidden'))`

Comment: What do you expect the intermittent step between `display:none` and `display:block` to look like?  (e.g. Do you expect it to be halfway slid in or halfway faded in?)  Anything you want to animate, try to envision what the middle step will be.  If you're animating opacity between `0` and `1` for instance the middle step will be `0.5`.  If you can envision that intermittent step, that's the property you want to animate.  In this case, `display` doesn't work.  There's no half step for `display` between `block` and `none`.

Answer (score 2):

there is no option like `display` in the `animate()` function because there are no steps between `display: block` and `display: none`. transitions can only be possible with numeric values.
take a look at the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/

use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question').on("click", function() {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    if(!$answer.is(':visible')) {
      $answer.fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: *"there is no option like display"* - this is highly inaccurate.

Comment: I don't think he's saying "an option like `display` doesn't exist"... He's saying that attributes without numeric values or "in-between" stages, like `display`, are not supported by `animate`.